Issues when displaying custom search results in Wordpress
I try to create my first search.php but I have some problems. When I launch a request, input's and filters' content disappear. It seems like my search's filters and input are reset when the result of my request is display.
How can I keep the parameters of my filters and input ?
After that, I also have a problem to display my posts. I have to use global $wp_query; which is not what I saw in tutorials. If I use my variable $query, WordPress' header display the correct search's results but displayed posts doesn't respect my filters by taxonomies.
Is there any problem to use this variable ?
Here is the basic form :
<form method="get" action=" <?php echo home_url('/') ?>">
    <div>
        <input type="search" name="s" />
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="recettes" />
        <input type="submit" value="Rechercher">
    </div>
    <select name="duree">
        <option value="0">Time</option>
        <?php
        $terms = get_terms('time', $filters_args);
        if (!empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
        ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $term->slug ?>"><?php echo $term->name ?> </option>
        <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>

Here is my request :
$s = get_search_query();
$filters_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$query_args = array(
    'post_type'         => array('recettes', 'post'),
    's'                 => $s,
    'posts_per_page'    => 15
);
$query = new WP_query($query_args);

Here what I use for displaying results :
global $wp_query;
if ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
        $wp_query->the_post();
?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php
    }
    wp_reset_query();
}

Thanks for your help !

If you are implementing the theme file search.php, the query is created for you, that's what global $wp_query; is about. You want to modify this query instead of creating a new one. Take a look at pre_get_posts. In there you will be given the current query, and you can inspect the is_search property to determine if you are in a search, and if so then you can tweak _that_query.

If you are creating your own dedicated search, independent of the built-in one, then I'd first rename the file because certain file names are magic in WordPress. Then on that page just don't use the global query and keep everything isolated to the variable you assign new WP_query() to. You will need to handle pagination on your own, too.

@ChrisHaas thanks for your answers ! Now I understand a little more how it works. I created a new search.php because it was easier than changing all the requests links. If it's a good practice, I will try to change links for using a file with another name !

Please update your code as per below
<form method="get" action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>">
    <div>
        <input type="search" name="s" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="recettes" />
        <input type="submit" value="Rechercher">
    </div>
    <select name="duree">
        <option value="0">Time</option>
        <?php
        $terms = get_terms('time', $filters_args);
        if (!empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                // Check if the current term is the one selected
                $selected = (isset($_GET['duree']) && $_GET['duree'] == $term->slug) ? 'selected' : '';
        ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>>
                    <?php echo $term->name; ?>
                </option>
        <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>

Here we can check if the taxonomy filter will applied then it will add tax_query
$filters_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$duree = isset($_GET['duree']) && $_GET['duree'] != '0' ? $_GET['duree'] : '';

$query_args = array(
    'post_type'         => array('recettes', 'post'),
    's'                 => $s,
    'posts_per_page'    => 15,
);

if ($duree) {
    $query_args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'time',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $duree,
        )
    );
}
$query = new WP_Query($query_args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php
    }
    // Reset post data
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    echo 'No posts found';
}


"Please update your code as per below" - Can you elaborate on the changes?

It works ! :) Thanks for your help. I will try to combine this solution and Chris' advices

Welcome . Please accept answer
